# how to make img disappear on hover?

Tags: html, image

How can I make an image in a webpage disappear when the user hovers over it?

Answer (score 5):

A little bit of CSS should solve this:

```
img:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously you'll want to specify a unique ID or class (depending on what behaviour you wanted).

Comment: :hover on images is buggy in IE, one should use the pseudo-class :hover only for links http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover

Comment: Thanks for that little tidbit. I'll be the first to admit that I haven't paid much attention to IE <9 recently, and I'm glad I'm in a position not to. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Image is hidden onhover:

```
<img onmouseover="this.style.visibility = 'hidden';" src="..." />
```

Image is hidden onhover and reappears after the mouse moves away

```
<img onmouseover="this.style.visibility = 'hidden';" onmouseout="this.style.visibility = 'visible';" src="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="test" name="test" onmouseover="document.getElementById('test_image').style.visibility= 'hidden';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('test_image').style.visibility= 'visible'">
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" id="test_image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and found display:none to be really glitchy.

Try this instead.

```
img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("image").hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast"); //fast(200 milisec) or slow(600 milisec)
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({"opacity: "1"}, "fast");
        });
    });
```